# Eclipse RCP throws exception when I try to use JPA for local data storage

Tags: java, jpa, eclipse-rcp, derby

I have the following code in my RCP application:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("todos");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
Query q = em.createQuery("select t from Todo t");
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Todo> todos = (List<Todo>)q.getResultList();
```

My config is META-INF/persistence.xml and contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="todos" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>foo.bar.Todo</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" 
                value="jdbc:derby:/home/pocon64/myDb;create=true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test" />

            <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->        
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
                value="database" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I try to run the application, it starts fine, but displays the error:

```
Could not create the view: 
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.ContextFinder@4b51ac10
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-30009] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while trying to load persistence unit at url: bundleresource://51.fwk2013125681:10
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-30004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while processing persistence.xml from URL: bundleresource://51.fwk2013125681:10
Internal Exception: 
(1. URI was not reported to parser for entity [document])
```

The db file isn't created at all. Any ideas what's causing this?

ADDITION: Full stack trace below:

```
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-30009] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while trying to load persistence unit at url: bundleresource://51.fwk998462082:10
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-30004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while processing persistence.xml from URL: bundleresource://51.fwk998462082:10
Internal Exception: 
(1. URI was not reported to parser for entity [document])
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionLoadingFromUrl(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:100)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceArchive(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:538)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.getPersistenceUnits(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:444)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfoInArchive(JPAInitializer.java:172)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfoInArchives(JPAInitializer.java:154)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfo(JPAInitializer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:73)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:60)
at com.diligentgaming.dcm.workstation.plugins.core.dashboard.DashboardView.createPartControl(DashboardView.java:64)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:375)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:229)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:313)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewPane.setVisible(ViewPane.java:534)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1245)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1198)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1597)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.createControl(PartStack.java:643)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.createControl(PartStack.java:570)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartSashContainer.createControl(PartSashContainer.java:568)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveHelper.activate(PerspectiveHelper.java:272)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.onActivate(Perspective.java:981)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.onActivate(WorkbenchPage.java:2714)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$28.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:3030)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setActivePage(WorkbenchWindow.java:3011)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.busyOpenPage(WorkbenchWindow.java:799)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$23.runWithException(Workbench.java:1229)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3938)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3615)
at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1600)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3938)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3615)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2609)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at com.diligentgaming.dcm.workstation.plugins.core.Application.start(Application.java:20)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-30004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while processing persistence.xml from URL: bundleresource://51.fwk998462082:10
Internal Exception: 
(1. URI was not reported to parser for entity [document])
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionProcessingPersistenceXML(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:118)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceXML(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:587)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceArchive(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:536)
... 63 more
Caused by: 
(1. URI was not reported to parser for entity [document])
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.xml.parser.XMLExceptionHandler.error(XMLExceptionHandler.java:28)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.xml.parser.XMLExceptionHandler.warning(XMLExceptionHandler.java:23)
at gnu.xml.aelfred2.SAXDriver.warn(SAXDriver.java:935)
at gnu.xml.aelfred2.SAXDriver.startExternalEntity(SAXDriver.java:631)
at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.pushURL(XmlParser.java:3358)
at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.doParse(XmlParser.java:159)
at gnu.xml.aelfred2.SAXDriver.parse(SAXDriver.java:320)
at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:294)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceXML(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:577)
... 64 more</code>
```

Comment: can you include the full stack trace, have you tried the same persistence unit in a non OSGi environment?

Comment: Hi James, I haven't tried in a non-OSGi environment, and this is the full stack trace. It looks like my persistence.xml is somehow at fault, but I'm not sure how, it looks OK to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be to remove the gnujaxp.jar from the Classpath, everything seems to work fine after that.